# Defining two functions at once

Tags: python, function

Is it possible to define two functions in a single function? I’ve made an attempt to simulate cleaning a dataset of dates:

```
#COMBINED FUNCTION

def combined_function(entry):
    for char in bad_chars:
        date = entry.replace(char,"")
    if "-" in date:
        split_date = date.split("-")
        date_one = int(split_date[0])
        date_two = int(split_date[1])
        date = (date_one+date_two)/2
        date = round(date)
    else:
        date = int(date)
    return(date)
```

When I run the new function on `test_data` is not yielding correct results:

```
test_data = ["1912", "1929", "1913-1923",
             "(1951)", "1994", "1934",
             "c. 1915", "1995", "c. 1912",
             "(1988)", "2002", "1957-1959",
             "c. 1955.", "c. 1970's",
             "C. 1990-1999"]
bad_chars = ["(",")","c","C",".","s","'", " "]

revised_date = []

for x in test_data:
    date = combined_function(x)
    revised_date.append(date)

print(revised_date)
```

I receive the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1951)'

Looks like an issue removing `bad_chars`.

Comment: What does this have to do with defining two functions at once? (And why are you throwing away the results of previous iterations of your `for char in bad_chars:` loop?)

Comment: Give your function a more sensible name – describing what it actually does – rather than the nondescript name "`combined_function`".

Comment: Apologies, in retrospect I see the confusion. Originally I was working to combine a function to remove certain characters with a second function to format the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your function parameter to `date`, and replace the `.replace` statement with `date = date.replace(char,"")`.

Function should look like this:

```py
def combined_function(date):
    for char in bad_chars:
        date = date.replace(char,"")
    if "-" in date:
        split_date = date.split("-")
        date_one = int(split_date[0])
        date_two = int(split_date[1])
        date = (date_one+date_two)/2
        date = round(date)
    else:
        date = int(date)
    return(date)
```

*Why is this happening??*

Simply because `date` is being replaced with `entry` in every iteration which remains unchanged by `.replace` statement.